# Programmatically retrieving Active Directory data faster than CSVDE or .NET

Tags: c#, c++, windows, active-directory

I'm a developer looking for the most performant way to retrieve Active Directory data from a domain controller.  In the past, I've experimented with the .NET API, and I've also used the CSVDE and LDIFDE command-line tools.

Is there is a more efficient and high-performance way do this programmatically?  I'm willing even to use C++ to do system-level programming, if necessary.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm building an application that looks for, and reports on, potential security issues on a client's Windows network.

Comment: How have you concluded that your implementations weren't fast enough? And why are you obsessed with finding the *fastest* way to do something as opposed to a solution that is fast enough? Before moving forward you need to profile your implementation. That will both give you baseline performance data as well as allow you to see, what's limiting you. For all we know you could be limited by a resource outside your control.

Answer (score 1):

.NET's [`System.DirectoryServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices) namespace (e.g. [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry)/[`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher)) is a wrapper over the native Windows Active Directory Services Interface ([ADSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/using-adsi)). The only performance hit is that it's a wrapper (the .NET component on top of the native C++).

But that's not where the performance bottleneck is. Whenever you're doing reports from AD, the biggest performance hit is from the network requests, so the key to performance is to keep network requests to a minimum and/or run the report as close to a domain controller as possible to minimize the round-trip time.

The [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement) namespace (e.g. [`UserPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal)) is a wrapper on top of `System.DirectoryServices` and, in my experience, is horribly slow because you lose control of how many requests go out to AD (for example, it routinely gets *all* attributes for AD objects even if you never use them).

If you want performance, use `System.DirectoryServices`. There are a few things to keep in mind to keep performance up:

1. When using `DirectorySearcher`, *always* add something to [`PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload). If you ask for nothing, it will return all attributes that have a value.
2. `DirectoryEntry` uses a property cache. If you access [`DirectoryEntry.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties), it will check to see if it has the property in its cache already. If not, it will ask AD for every attribute with a value. To avoid this, you can populate the cache with specific attributes by using [`DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache), like this:

```
de.RefreshCache(new[] {"company", "sAMAccountName"});
var company = de.Properties["company"]?.Value as string;
var username = de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value as string;
```

3. Because of 1 & 2, when going through the results of a search, don't use [`SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry) just for the purpose of reading `Properties`. Otherwise, you'll end up going back to AD to get attributes that you could have gotten during the search. Use `PropertiesToLoad` instead.
4. If you're doing a report, you're likely looping over many accounts, which is a lot of processing. This means that .NET's garbage collector won't have time to run until the loop ends. So make sure you dispose of `DirectoryEntry` objects you create (either manually, or put them in a `using` statement) before you move on to the next account. Otherwise your program will consume a ton of memory (this happened to me).
5. When using [`DirectorySearcher.FindAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall), make sure you dispose of the results (again, either by calling `.Dispose()` or put it in a `using` statement). The documentation says that you will end up with memory leaks if you don't.

There is probably more than can be said, but it depends on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and see how well it performs!